# jax-rs client to download file

Tags: java, jax-rs

In my project I am calling a rest service which returns `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` .
I have written a jersey client for the same. But I am not getting `500` error.
In the logs I saw error :

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, genericType=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.
```

The code written is as follows ,

```
 ClientConfig clientConfig = null;
        Client client = null;
        WebTarget webTarget = null;
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = null;
        Response response = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        int responseCode;
        String responseMessageFromServer = null;
        String responseString = null;
        String qualifiedDownloadFilePath = null;

        try{
            // invoke service after setting necessary parameters
            clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
           // clientConfig.register(MultiPartWriter.class);
            //clientConfig.register(MessageBodyWriter.class);
            clientConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);


            client =  ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
            client.property("accept", "application/octet-stream");
            webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/EarchivePOC/archive/1");

            // invoke service
            invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
            //          invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
            response = invocationBuilder.get();

            // get response code
            responseCode = response.getStatus();
            System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
```

Could someone please help if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = response.readEntity(ByteArrayInputStream.class);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(bais, baos); // IOUtils from commons-io
```